# ASP.NET Web API GET Method: Passing multiple values for single parameter

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am fairly new to ASP.NET Web API.

I am trying to build an API method that can handle multiple values for a single parameter from a search client.

The criteria needs to be a OR search for eg. A color search for Red OR Blue OR Green.

I pass the colors as integer to my method. Please find my controller method below which fails to compile with the following error

Errors:

> Error  1   'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, TSource)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error  2   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Code:

```
public IQueryable<Items> GetItemByColour(string Colour)
{
    int[] intArr = Array.ConvertAll(Colour.Split(','), s => int.Parse(s));

    var query = from a in db.Items
                where a.ItemsColour.Contains(intArr)
                select a;

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have two different issues there. The first one is that you don't need to send the Colors list as a string and convert it to an integer array manually, you can do it like this instead:

```
public IQueryable<Items> GetItemByColour([FromUri] int[] Colour)
```

And you're getting an error in your LINQ query because `a.ItemColour` is an integer, not an integer list, therefore you can't use the `Contains` extension method on it. You have to do it like this (assuming `Colour` is now an integer array):

```
var query = from a in db.Items
            where Colour.Contains(a.ItemsColour)
            select a;

return query;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, its definitely the correct way. The only problem is I am using WP8 app to consume the Web API and use a Web Client. Not sure how you would pass an array using a Web Client

Comment: It's fairly easy, you do it like this: example-url.com/?Colour=1&Colorur=2&Colour=3. In this example, every instance of the Colour query-string variable will be an item in the Colour array. This way your service is also more interoperable.
Regarding your question, I did also point out the other issue you had and how to solve it. :)

Comment: This is by far the best way to go.  By passing a string, it requires you to do type checking to prevent any [int.Parse `FormatException`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx).

Comment: that's perfect! Wasn't aware of that. Wasted 3 hours of my life trying to get it work earlier!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will be the solution to your issue:

```
public IQueryable<Items> GetItemByColour(string Colour)
{
    List<int> intArr = Array.ConvertAll(Colour.Split(','), s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();

    var query = from a in db.Items
                where a.intArr.Contains(ItemsColour)
                select a;

    return query;
}
```

The problem was that you were looking for the presence of an array in an int. You need to look for the presence of an int in the array